# Json Parsing in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I get the json on console as

```
 [Object]
    0: Object
    address: "soham"
    region: "soham"
    relevanceScore: "4"
    startDate: "2015-05-10"
    subscriptionType: "1"
    verificationStatus: "1"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

and my ajax call

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
   {
    ($.ajax({       
       url:"allServices/getBusinessDetails.php?busid=<? echo $business_id; ?>",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (jsondata) {
        var allval=jsondata;            
        console.log(allval);
}
    }));      
});
```

but when i try to take the value out of it as **allval.address** it gives me undefined.
How to parse the object

Comment: And `allval[0].address` ?

Comment: Notice `0`. it's an arrayed json  `"[{},{},{}]"` - hence look at dystroy's access to the array ( once it's parsed)

Comment: thank you.. allval[0].address worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() 
   {
    ($.ajax({       
       url:"allServices/getBusinessDetails.php?busid=<? echo $business_id; ?>",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (jsondata) {
        var allval=JSON.stringify(jsondata);            
        console.log(allval[0].address);
        }
    }));      
});
```

I'm not sure but i think its helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, that's it.. it worked.. but what this allval[0] is for, it returns json and we can parse the value or get it directly , and why allval gives undifined

Comment: I'm not sure but when you want to parse your response then you try `JSON.stringify(response)` and i think your response is in array that contain only one object so i am use `allval[0]`. you want to address from this object so i am use `allval[0].address`.

Answer (score 2):

if you send data as `json` on server you can use `responce.data` but you can `dumps` json object and send it as string, and use `var r = JSON.parse(responce)`

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the actual situation :

Assume you have array of objects :

```
var  g = [{a:1,b:2},{c:1,d:2}];
```

Let's convert it to json string :

```
var json  = JSON.stringify(g); //"[{"a":1,"b":2},{"c":1,"d":2}]"
```

Now , this is your situation :

the server returns  :

```
"[{"a":1,"b":2},{"c":1,"d":2}]"
```

How can you parse it ?

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
```

Great. now let's look how the browser sees it :

[image]

so how would you access the first item ?

Right , via `[0]` like dystroy write in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("allServices/getBusinessDetails.php?busid=<? echo $business_id; ?>",function(data){

         $.each(data,function(key,value){
             alert(data[key].attrib1name);
             alert(data[key].attrib2name); 

             console.log(value);
         });
     });    


});
```

Or this approach

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("allServices/getBusinessDetails.php?busid=<? echo $business_id; ?>",function(data){

           parseJsonArray(data);


    });


function parseJsonArray(obj) {
        // Do something.
        $.each(obj, function (idx, obj1) {


            if (typeof obj1 == 'object') {
                parseJsonArray(obj1);

            } else {


                           alert(idx+":"+obj1);

            }

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery.parseJSON

like this `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );`

see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

If you get undefined the data you are trying to parse is probebly unvalid.
You can try if its valid here
http://pro.jsonlint.com